# How create subtask with python-asana

Tags: python, asana, asana-api

How to create subtask with python-asana?

I can create a task, but how to create subtask in the task?

```
client.tasks.create(name=task[0], projects=ASANA_PROJECT_ID, workspace=ASANA_WORKSPACE_ID, notes=notes)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a convenience method on the tasks resource, `add_subtask`, that you can use. Also keep in mind that you can always call arbitrary routes in the API using the library's `client().get()`,`client().post()`,`client().put()` &`client().delete()` methods.

`parent_task = client.tasks.create(name=task[0], projects=ASANA_PROJECT_ID, workspace=ASANA_WORKSPACE_ID, notes=notes)`

`client.tasks.add_subtask(parent_task['id'], {'name': 'This is a subtask'})`

https://asana.com/developers/api-reference/tasks#subtasks